# java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@545b995e;

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

I am getting below error when I am starting server or triggering pipeline.

> java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class:
> oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver from
> ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@545b995e;

I checked in `lib` folder of Tomcat and `ojdbc jar` was also missing

I checked in `pom.xml`, and dependency was missing, so I put below dependency in pom.xml and triggered a build again.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Still, I am getting same issue. Below is the detail log. What could be the possible reason?

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@545b995e;ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@545b995e
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:316)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:228)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:764)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:692)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:496)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:121)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:110)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:560)
```

Comment: It looks like you're using the data source config of Tomcat itself, in that case, you need to have the JAR file of the Oracle JDBC driver in the `lib` folder of Tomcat itself. Also, `<scope>provided</scope>` means that at runtime **you** already have the driver available, and don't expect Maven to include the driver for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you check in maven repo, does not exists the 8.0 version, the correct version is [19.3.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.ojdbc/ojdbc8)